# HTML pass parameter from url to Embed flash object

Tags: html, flash, url, parameters

I would like to get FilePath parameter from url example:
http://www.example.com/index.html?FilePath=LetsGo

browsing this will pass it to html flash player script ("LetsGo" will play instead of "autoload"):

```
<html>
<body><.......
<object classid="123456...." codebase="http://123457" id="test" height="300" align="middle" width="300">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="movie" value="123.swf">
    <param name="FlashVars" value="MP3=autoload.mp3&amp;JPG=autoload.jpg&amp;repeats=200">
    <embed src="123.swf" allowfullscreen="true" name="MP3JPG" flashvars="MP3=autoload.mp3&amp;JPG=autoload.jpg&amp;repeats=200" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" height="300" align="middle" width="300">
</object><......
</html>
```

How can i do that currectly?

Many thanks,

Bentzy.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to get your URL parameters is to use jQuery URL Parser, here you can get this utility.

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser/master/purl.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var filePath = $.url().param('FilePath');    

        //cool!
        alert(filePath);

        var flashObjectHtml = "<object classid='clsid:d27...' codebase='http://...' id='test' height='300' align='middle' width='300'> \
          <param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'> \
          <param name='movie' value='123.swf'> \
          <param name='FlashVars' value='MP3=" + filePath + "&amp;JPG=autoload.jpg&amp;repeats=200'> \
          <embed src='123.swf' allowfullscreen='true' name='MP3JPG' flashvars='MP3=" + filePath + "&amp;JPG=autoload.jpg&amp;repeats=200' \
          type='application/x-shockwave-flash' pluginspage='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer' height='300' \
          align='middle' width='300'> \
        </object>";

        $('#flash_wrapper').html(flashObjectHtml);

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="flash_wrapper"></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**EDIT**

Copy the above script, save and call it this way in your browser:

```
[the_path_where_you_saved_this_file]/some_name.htm?FilePath=some_path
```

**An important point**: these URL parameters are case sensitive, so FilePath != filepath != filePath

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is not working for me..
tried to put some alerts to find out what the problem is but couldn't find why.
the alert before "var filepath" popup but the one after that not..

Comment: Well, are you referencing the "jquery.url.parser.js" correctly? Did you get it and put in the same folder of your html? Here it works perfectly.

Comment: Another point: the argument name in the url is case sensitive, so FilePath != Filepath != filepath...

Comment: I edited the answer, please try to follow the instructions above.

Comment: The line that get the url didn't work for me, i tried another way to retrieve the url and now everything work.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @user1199838 and? what was it?